# Why does LaunchedEffect work but not collectAsFlowWithLifecycle()?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

I want to update some text in a @Composable in response to events.  I found an example of how to emit the event data as a flow using `channelFlow` and when I went to use that in my composable, `collectAsStateWithLifecycle` only showed the updated state values on lifecycle changes (screen rotation), however the solution below using `LaunchedEffect` works just fine.  Any insight into what I did wrong trying to collect as state?  From what I can tell, `event.values` always has the same address, so presumably that's the main issue, but I don't know the a better fix than emitting a copy, which seems inefficient.

```kotlin
val gyroFlow : Flow<FloatArray> = getGyroData(gyroscope, sensorManager)
//...
setContent {
//works
                    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = gyroFlow) {

                        gyroFlow.collect {gyroReading ->
                            text = "Gyro reading: ${gyroReading[0]} ${gyroReading[1]} ${gyroReading[2]}"
                        }
                    }
                    Text(text = text)

//only updates on lifecycle changes
//                    val gyroReading by gyroFlow.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(
//                        floatArrayOf(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
//                        lifecycleOwner = this@MainActivity
//                    )
//               Text(text = "Gyro reading: ${gyroReading[0]} ${gyroReading[1]} ${gyroReading[2]}")
                }



fun getGyroData(gyroscope: Sensor, sensorManager: SensorManager): Flow<FloatArray> {
    return channelFlow {
        val listener = object : SensorEventListener {
            override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {
                if (event !== null) {
                    Log.e("Sensor event!", event.values.toString()) //always the same address
                    var success = channel.trySend(event.values).isSuccess
                    Log.e("success?", success.toString())
                }
            }
        }
        sensorManager.registerListener(listener, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)

        awaitClose {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener)
        }
    }
}
```